# Problemas em configurar origem permitida do CORS Spring Boot!

Tags: spring-boot, cors

Essa é a mensagem de erro que está dando;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com dificuldade de fazer minha API Front-End ter permissão de acesso a minha API Back-End que é um projeto Spring Boot, eu tenho certeza que meu problema não é minha API Fron-End, o problema está na configuração do CORS em relação a permissão de acesso.

vou deixa as configuração do meu CORS logo abaixo

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import br.com.mdw.config.MdwApiProperty;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private MdwApiProperty mdwApiProperty;


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", mdwApiProperty.getOriginPermitida());
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod()) && mdwApiProperty.getOriginPermitida().equals(request.getHeader("Origin"))) {
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }

}


    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

E aqui onde configuro o acesso:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties("mdw")
public class MdwApiProperty {

    private String originPermitida = "http://localhost:8000";

    private final Seguranca seguranca = new Seguranca();

    public Seguranca getSeguranca() {
        return seguranca;
    }

    public String getOriginPermitida() {
        return originPermitida;
    }

    public void setOriginPermitida(String originPermitida) {
        this.originPermitida = originPermitida;
    }

    public static class Seguranca {

        private boolean enableHttps;

        public boolean isEnableHttps() {
            return enableHttps;
        }

        public void setEnableHttps(boolean enableHttps) {
            this.enableHttps = enableHttps;
        }

}


}
```

Foi criado uma classe chamada MdwApiProperty

Onde foi colocada a seguinte anotação:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("mdw")
```

E por causa dessa anotação é por isso no arquivo application-prod.properties aceitou essa linha de código.

```java
mdw.seguranca.enable-https=true
```

Se isso for verdade se eu por acaso modificar a anotação da classe MdwApiProperty para

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("habilitando-producao")
```

Iria fica assim no arquivo application-prod.properties .

```java
habilitando-producao.seguranca.enable-https=true
```

E nesse arquivos onde habilita o apelido para  acesso ao projeto

```java
package br.com.mdw;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

import br.com.mdw.config.MdwApiProperty;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MdwApiProperty.class)
public class MdwApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MdwApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

É aqui onde fica a anotação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```java
mdw.seguranca.enable-https=true

spring.datasource.url={JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.username={JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password={JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}

mdw.origin-permitida=https://mdw-arm-wladimir.herokuapp.com
```

Por algum motivo ele não está aceitando o acesso, preciso de ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desativa a sua implementação CORs do SPRING e tenta usar uma destas 2 (duas) soluções:

**Solução 1:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import com.example.algamoney.api.config.property.AlgamoneyApiProperty;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AlgamoneyApiProperty algamoneyApiProperty;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        CorsConfiguration configAutenticacao = new CorsConfiguration();
        configAutenticacao.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configAutenticacao.addAllowedOrigin(algamoneyApiProperty.getOriginPermitida());
        configAutenticacao.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
        configAutenticacao.addAllowedHeader("Content-Type");
        configAutenticacao.addAllowedHeader("Accept");
        configAutenticacao.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        configAutenticacao.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        configAutenticacao.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        configAutenticacao.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        configAutenticacao.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        configAutenticacao.setMaxAge(3600L);
        // source.registerCorsConfiguration("/oauth/token", configAutenticacao);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configAutenticacao); // Global para todas as URLs da aplicação

        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

**Solução 2:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.algamoney.api.config.property.AlgamoneyApiProperty;

@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private AlgamoneyApiProperty algamoneyApiProperty;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", algamoneyApiProperty.getOriginPermitida());
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod()) && algamoneyApiProperty.getOriginPermitida().equals(request.getHeader("Origin"))) {
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Content-Type, Accept");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");

            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

**Observação:** Você deve efetuar o debugger do código e verificar se a chamada está entrando na primeira chamada: "OPTIONS"`.equals(request.getMethod())`, pois o navegador sempre executa uma requisição "OPTIONS" antes da chamada que você requisitou.